# Can I write a title on a CARTO map?

Tags: carto, title

I close a project with CARTO on the website (no through coding) but I don't see where and how to write a title on the export map. 
It was possible with CartoDB but I didn't found solution with CARTO.
I didn't found any solution but looks crazy that none didn't think to write a "header title" to the map.

Answer (score 2):

[As mentioned in the first Learn Guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations), elements (title, text and images) are not temporary available in CARTO BUILDER. As a workaround, you can *prepend* a header to a custom legend.

Comment: This still amazes me. Worked like a charm in the old version and now sill waiting for it, but hopeful;-)

Comment: Editor was focused on data visualization, BUILDER is more into analysis and widgets. CARTO is rethinking the best way to tell stories with maps, but I doubt that overlays will be the solution (disclaimer: I work at CARTO).